# ifup(8) equivalent code in C

Tags: c, linux

I have been searching the source code of `ifup`, but I could not find any. Instead, I modified [ifdown.c](https://raw.github.com/pmundt/kexec-tools-sh/master/kexec/ifdown.c) a little bit and have the following code:

```
int ifup(char interface[])
{
    struct ifreq ifr[64];
    struct ifconf ifc;
    int i, fd;
    int numif;
    int shaper;

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ifdown: ");
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(ifr);
    ifc.ifc_req = ifr;

    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ifup: ");
        perror("SIOCGIFCONF");
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
    numif = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);

    for (shaper = 1; shaper >= 0; shaper--) {
        for (i = 0; i < numif; i++) {
            if (strcmp(ifr[i].ifr_name, interface) == 0){
                ifr[i].ifr_flags |= (IFF_UP);
                if (ioctl(fd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr[i]) < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ifup: shutdown ");
                    perror(ifr[i].ifr_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

if I do `ifdown("wlan0");` and `ifup("wlan0");` by using the above code,it disables then enables the interface. At the end, I see that the interface has an IP address and essid, etc. on iwconfig. I can ping my router, however, I cannot ping any domain or a direct IP address

`ping 74.125.232.98` outputs

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

unless I disconnect and connect to my router again via the network manager.

there is no such issue if I use [ifup(8)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ifup&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%205.0%20lenny&format=html&locale=en) from the terminal.

Could anyone tell me what else needs to be done on the above code for it to work as `ifup(8)`?

Comment: Try a `whereis` on your system and see, sometimes it will come with the source.

Comment: The source for Debians ifup can be found here: http://anonscm.debian.org/hg/collab-maint/ifupdown/

Comment: The Ubuntu's ifupdown can be downloaded from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ifupdown_0.7.45ubuntu1.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a default route. `ifup` command automatically sets up a default route for you. You can see this by running `$ route -n` before an `ifup` call and after.

btw Thank you for the code it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to setup the routing too before you can reach external hosts